# Trimming byte array when converting byte array to string in Java/Scala

Tags: java, string, scala, arrays

Using ByteBuffer, I can convert a string into byte array:

```
val x = ByteBuffer.allocate(10).put("Hello".getBytes()).array()
> Array[Byte] = Array(104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

When converting the byte array into string, I can use `new String(x)`.
However, the string becomes `hello?????`, and I need to trim down the byte array before converting it into string. How can I do that?

I use this code to trim down the zeros, but I wonder if there is simpler way.

```
def byteArrayToString(x: Array[Byte]) = {
    val loc = x.indexOf(0)
    if (-1 == loc)
      new String(x)
    else if (0 == loc)
      ""
    else
      new String(x.slice(0,loc))
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that `0: Byte` is a trailing value, then

```
implicit class RichToString(val x: java.nio.ByteBuffer) extends AnyVal {
  def byteArrayToString() = new String( x.array.takeWhile(_ != 0), "UTF-8" )
}
```

Hence for

```
val x = ByteBuffer.allocate(10).put("Hello".getBytes())

x.byteArrayToString
res: String = Hello
```

Answer (score 4):

Several of the [String constructors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) accepts an offset+length into a `byte[]` - this eliminates the need to create a new trimmed array before hand.

Using one of the overloaded constructors might look like:

```
def byteArrayToString(x: Array[Byte]) = {
    val loc = x.indexOf(0)
    if (-1 == loc)
      new String(x)
    else if (0 == loc)
      ""
    else
      new String(x, 0, loc, "UTF-8") // or appropriate encoding
}
```

Or, a slight variation keeping the indexOf:

```
def byteArrayToString(arr: Array[Byte]) = {
    val loc = arr.indexOf(0)
    // length passed to constructor can be 0..arr.length
    new String(arr, 0, if (loc >= 0) loc else arr.length, "UTF-8")
}
```

Or, one line (thanks to find/Option):

```
def byteArrayToString(arr: Array[Byte]) = {
    new String(arr, 0, arr.find(_ == 0) orElse arr.length, "UTF-8")
}
```

---

Thoughts on the encoding:

1. Using an explicit encoding is often recommended, and the same encoding should be used specified in `getBytes`, as the [default may change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding). Here are the [standard charset names](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).
2. The byte `0` *may* appear in encoded output *before* the end of the data, depending on the String input (i.e. NUL) and encoding used.

Answer (score 2):

If you just have one `String`, I would use `.getBytes()` -

```
val x:Array[Byte] = "Hello".getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Output is

```
x: Array[Byte] = Array(72, 101, 108, 108, 111)
```

For more then one `String`, I would use a [ByteArrayOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), like so -

```
val baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream(10); //  <-- I might not use 10.
                                                  //  <-- Smells of premature opt.
baos.write("Hello".getBytes("UTF-8"));
baos.write(", World!".getBytes("UTF-8"));

val x:Array[Byte] = baos.toByteArray(); // <-- x:Array[Byte], to specify the type.
```

Output is

```
x: Array[Byte] = Array(72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 87, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
val bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(10).put("Hello".getBytes)
val s = new String(bb.array, 0, bb.position)
```

though this won't indicate in the ByteBuffer that you've read anything.  The normal pattern would be to `flip` and use `limit`, but if you're just grabbing the array you may as well just use `position` instead and `clear` when you're done before reading more.